# Python Scrapy: How to get CSVItemExporter to write columns in a specific order

Tags: csv, scrapy

In Scrapy, I have my items specified in a certain order in items.py, & my spider has those items again in the same order. However, when I run the spider & save the results as a csv, the column order from the items.py or the spider is not maintained. How can I get the CSV to show columns in a specific order. Example code would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

This is related to [Modifiying CSV export in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245047/modifiying-csv-export-in-scrapy)

The problem is that the exporter is instantiated without any keyword parameters, so the keywords like EXPORT_FIELDS are ignored.  The solution is the same: you need to subclass the CSV item exporter to pass the keyword parameters.

Following the above recipe, I created a new file xyzzy/feedexport.py (change "xyzzy" to whatever your scrapy class is named):

```
"""
The standard CSVItemExporter class does not pass the kwargs through to the
CSV writer, resulting in EXPORT_FIELDS and EXPORT_ENCODING being ignored
(EXPORT_EMPTY is not used by CSV).
"""

from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter

class CSVkwItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['fields_to_export'] = settings.getlist('EXPORT_FIELDS') or None
        kwargs['encoding'] = settings.get('EXPORT_ENCODING', 'utf-8')

        super(CSVkwItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then added it into xyzzy/settings.py:

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'xyzzy.feedexport.CSVkwItemExporter'
}
```

Now the CSV exporter will honor the EXPORT_FIELD setting - also add to xyzzy/settings.py:

```
# By specifying the fields to export, the CSV export honors the order
# rather than using a random order.
EXPORT_FIELDS = [
    'field1',
    'field2',
    'field3',
]
```

Comment: I see this post is already quite old. Has this issue been resolved in more simple way in a more recent release?

Comment: please fix this in your answer `from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter`

Comment: @HozayfaElRifai Thanks,`from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporte`' should be `from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter`.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't know about the time you asked your question but Scrapy now provides a **fields_to_export** attribute to the *BaseItemExporter* class, from which *CsvItemExporter* inherits.
As per version 0.22:

> **fields_to_export**
>
> > A list with the name of the fields that will be exported, or None if you want to export all fields. Defaults to None.
> >
> > Some exporters (like *CsvItemExporter*) respect the order 
> >     of the fields defined in this attribute.

See also the documentation for [BaseItemExporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.BaseItemExporter.fields_to_export) and [CsvItemExporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#csvitemexporter) on the Scrapy website.

In order to use this feature, though, you will have to create your own ItemPipeline, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20758558/3209799)