# How to override join_multivalued option of CsvItemExporter

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

[CsvItemExporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.CsvItemExporter) has an option `join_multivalued` that defaults to a comma (`=','`).

How can i change this to another char in my scrapy project?

Comment: Could you show how do you currently use `CsvItemExporter`?

Comment: Like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943778/python-scrapy-how-to-get-csvitemexporter-to-write-columns-in-a-specific-order/7465854#7465854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it in your custom `CSVItemExporter` this way:

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter

class CSVkwItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['fields_to_export'] = settings.getlist('EXPORT_FIELDS') or None
        kwargs['encoding'] = settings.get('EXPORT_ENCODING', 'utf-8')

        super(CSVkwItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._join_multivalued = settings.get('MY_CSV_DELIMITER', ',')
```

where `MY_CSV_DELIMITER` is an example setting you would have for a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

## Scrapy version 1.5.0

#### your_scrapy_project/exporters.py

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

class MyCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        delimiter = settings.get('CSV_DELIMITER', ';')
        kwargs['delimiter'] = delimiter

        super(MyCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### your_scrapy_project/settings.py

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'

FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'your_scrapy_project.exporters.MyCsvItemExporter',
}

CSV_DELIMITER = ';'
```