# Scrapy CLI output - CSV_DELIMITER parameter not working

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, web-crawler, delimiter

I am trying to run the scrapy exporter with a custom delimiter via CLI like this:

`scrapy runspider beneficiari_2016.py -o beneficiari_2016.csv -t csv -a CSV_DELIMITER="\n"`

The export works perfectly, but the delimiter is still the default comma(",").

Please let me know if you have any idea how it can be fixed. Thank you!

*The code:*

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import urllib.parse

class anmdm(Item):
    nume_beneficiar = Field()

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.anm.ro/sponsorizari/afisare-2016/beneficiari?
    page=1']
    def parse(self, response):
        doctor = anmdm()
        doctors = []
        for item in response.xpath('//tbody/tr'):
            doctor['nume_beneficiar'] = 
        item.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract_first()
            yield doctor
        next_page =  response.xpath("//ul/li[@class='active']/following-
       sibling::li/a/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            print(next_page)
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/28097557/2572383

Answer (score 0):

CSV_DELIMITER needs to be changed in `settings` and not like an spider argument `-a`.

To change settings on the command line use `-s`:

```
scrapy runspider beneficiari_2016.py -o beneficiari_2016.csv -t csv -s CSV_DELIMITER="\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Sadly adding '-s CSV_DELIMITER="\n"' is not working -- the CSV delimiter is still the default comma. FYI, I am using Scrapy 1.4.0 with Python3 on Mac.

Comment: This is the right way to override settings actually. Indeed you should be using -s instead of -a. But With Scrapy 1.4.0 and Python3 I have the same problem. It is still comma in the file.