# Scrapy Selector Code in CSV output - is this an OS X, XPaths or Scrapy issue?

Tags: python, csv, xpath, scrapy

Learning about Scrapy and XPaths and running into a few problems. Most recently, that: scrapy crawl GCSpider -o items.csv -t csv returns a CSV file that contains (most) of the data I want, but with scrapy selector code muddled in with the data (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BAvg.png)).

Another point of confusion is that the column headers are ordered differently from the order set for scraping & in items. Why is this?

The spider code is as follows:

```
     # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
    from scrapy.selector import Selector

    from scraper_app.items import GenomeCanadaGrants

    class GCSpider(Spider):
        """Spider for Genome Canada Awards page."""
        name = 'GCSpider'
        allowed_domains = ["http://genomereports.ca"]
        start_urls= ["http://genomereports.ca/section.php?Action=List2&Lang=En&addnew=&Report=consolidated_commitments.php&Report_Text=Funding+Commitments&Nav=Section&ID=3&Login=&Password=&Consolidated_Centre=ALL&Consolidated_Category=ALL&Consolidated_Sector=ALL&Consolidated_Competition=ALL&Consolidated_FY=ALL&Consolidated_Status=ALL"]


def parse(self, response):

    sel = Selector(response)
    grants = sel.css('div#content_frame table tr')
    items = []

    for response in grants:
        item = GenomeCanadaGrants()
        item['Province'] = response.xpath('.//th[1]//text()').extract()  # Column Header: CENTRE
        item['Sector'] = response.xpath('.//th[2]//text()').extract()  # Column Header: SECTOR
        item['Fund'] = response.xpath('.//th[3]//text()').extract()  # Column Header: PROGRAM & Fiscal Yr Awarded
        item['Date'] = response.xpath('.//th[3]//text()').re('\d+\d-\d+\d')  # Column Header: PROGRAM & Fiscal Yr Awarded
        item['Status'] = response.xpath('.//th[4]//text()').extract  # Column Header: STATUS
        item['Principal_Investigator'] = response.xpath('.//th[5]//text()').extract()  # Column Header: PROJECT LEADER(S)
        item['Project_Title'] = response.xpath(".//th[6]//text()").extract  # Column Header: PROJECT TITLE
        item['Additional_Information'] = response.xpath(".//th[6]//a[@href='url']").extract  # Link to PDF with Project Details
        item['Amount'] = response.xpath('.//th[7]//text()').extract  # Column Header: APPROVED BUDGET
        item['GC_Contribution'] = response.xpath('.//th[8]//text()').extract  # Column Header: GC CONTRIBUTION
        # Perhaps this line should be yield item?
        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @amow said, some of your extract should be changed to extract() to solve the selectors in the ouput issue.

The order of the fields in the CSV file can be set using an item exporter. Here is the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter), and for an example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943778/python-scrapy-how-to-get-csvitemexporter-to-write-columns-in-a-specific-order).

Comment: For CSV output, you only need to set [`FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS) to specify the order

Answer (score 0):

1.miss the `()` after `extract` keywords at so many columns.So it gives you function object instead of it's selector value.
2.the order of key you define will not affect the output order. Because it is like normal dict.I dont have solutions to that now.