# How to change csv exporter separator in Scrapy to semicolon?

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I'm new in Scrapy. I have read several discussions about this tool. I have a problem exporting csv files. I'm scrapping numeric values with commas. The default separatos of csv exporter is comma, so I have some problems when I open the resulting file in Excel.

How can I change the default delimitor of csv files in Scrapy to semicolon? I read some discussions about this issue but I don't know what and where i have to add code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifiying CSV export in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245047/modifiying-csv-export-in-scrapy)

Answer (score 7):

**scraper/exporters.py**

```py
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter


class CsvCustomSeperator(CsvItemExporter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['encoding'] = 'utf-8'
        kwargs['delimiter'] = '╡'
        super(CsvCustomSeperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**scraper/settings.py**

```py
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'scraper.exporters.CsvCustomSeperator'
}
```

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if quotechar is enabled and set in your export.

```
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=CSV_DELIMITER#csvfeedspider-example
```

Usually text should be enquoted with " so it's no issue that the delimiter is in the text.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
scrapy crawl yourCrawlerName -o output.csv --set delimiter=";"
```

Comment: @DhruvGhulati I do not get your point. Are you confusing me with the author of the question?