# How to change delimiter in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I looked through the other topics like my, but didn't find the answer. How i can change the basic delimiter "," to ";" in my Scrapy project.

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you mean in CSV? Like this (btw, lineterminator done same way, `kwargs['lineterminator'] = lineterminator`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245047/modifiying-csv-export-in-scrapy